# How do I get coefficients of columns from a fit_resamples object?

Tags: r, tidymodels

Where does `fit_resamples()` get its coefficients for each of the columns it predicted/fitted?

Essentially, between the two pictures below, I need to get something like the second picture, not the first picture.

When looking at the object that `fit_resamples()` spits out, it results into this: [image: What happens, but don't want]

But I would like something like this: [image: What I got without fit_resamples, but want]

When looking at the docs, examples, etc. (for example https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/work/tune-text/#extracted-results), they only show first picture.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please don't post pictures of data. We cant test code with images.

Comment: You might want to look at how to use [`extract_fit_engine()`](https://tune.tidymodels.org/reference/extract-tune.html) within a resampling function, as [in this article](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/work/tune-text/#grid-search).